# Update Upload Process Details in TextBox Along with Upload in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF window, I am uploading a large Excel file to internal database. I want to show the update process like which sheet it is reading etc in the text box below.

- I tried writing text in text box/ updating label content but it just holds in freeze till operation is over. For both textbox and label only first item gets updated and holds still till last item.
- I tried using another thread but since wpf runs on single thread, it doesnt allow the new thread to take control of wpf window items

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: you have to do the upload in for example another thread, or run it as a task. NEVER use the UI thread for calculations

Comment: I tried that too (shifted the entire excel writing process to a new thread and it starts on submit button click), but still get error message that "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **NEVER** use the UI thread for other things, if you want to program good software! Things like uploading, you put in a thread or in a task, which of course has **NO** access to the UI elements, but **there is a dispatcher for that**.

```
private void CopyTask()
{
     Task.Run(() =>
     {
          //here comes in your task that takes a long time. 
          //But you can still move your window in the time.
          UpdateText("10$");
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          UpdateText("20$");
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          UpdateText("50$");
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          UpdateText("100$");
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     });
}


private void UpdateText(string Value)
{
     //checks if it has access, if not then it goes through the dispatcher,
     //which can call the method with the necessary rights
     if (!Txtbox.CheckAccess())
          Txtbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
          {
               UpdateText(Value);
          });
          else
               Txtbox.Text = Value;
}
```

But I would recommend you to learn first what WPF, Threads and Dispatcher are.